# GWT table (ideally Datagrid) rotated

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

can be odd but and beside I think it is a common problem I can't find any googling: I would like to insert in my gwt application a table with data that grows horizontally instead that by rows.
What i mean is that i will have a fixed number of rows and a dynamic number of columns, practically a data grid rotated by 90°.
I found this piece of code:
https://code.google.com/p/gwt-data-binding/source/browse/trunk/src/ca/petersens/gwt/databinding/client/ui/DataGrid.java?r=21
but seems something far to be standard and not much manageable in long term projects.
It exists any better solution?

UPDATE:
the idea is have data grid advantages like scrolling and lazy load for a big amount of data...the direct use of columns as rows isn't a good solution.

UPDATE:
a try i'm doing is extend abstracthasdata to implement my own feature but i'm not able to create a div with a scollbar! external containers are all "100%" (let say I cannot set them to a fixed size)
and my override of renderRowValues appends something like

""
and my table data and related tag closures

but such a way the result is that no scrollbar happens, just a page with high wide!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standards DataGrid with the data type set to a `<String>` or `<MyHeader>`, where `MyHeader` is an Enum representing row headers. You add a set of Strings or values of this Enum to your data  provider.

Your first column will be a TextColumn that displays the object itself. Then you can use `addColumn` (or `insertColumn`) methods to add other columns that represent your data. Something like:

```
final ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects;
for (MyObject myObject : MyObjects) {
    TextColumn textColumn = new TextColumn<HeaderEnum>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(HeaderEnum header) {
            for (MyObject myObject : MyObjects) {
                if (myObject.getSomeProperty().equals(header.name()) {
                    return myObject.getAnotherPropertyAsString();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    myGrid.addColumn(textColumn);
    myGrid.setColumnWidth(textColumn, "100px");
}
```

Comment: this strategy will add columns in a traditional way but will generate performance issues and won't support lazy load on scrolling (i doubt scrolling it self will be working)

Comment: If you plan to add many (dozens of) columns, I have a serious doubt that users will like your solution. There is a good reason why you don't see a widget like that - this is not a standard UI approach. In fact, I don't remember ever seeing it. There will be no performance issues for 5-12 columns.

Comment: Timeline widgets are good example of why many columns can be needed...I need a table that don't go vertically by rows but horizontally by columns...users will love it imho :)

Comment: I have a DataGrid that displays up to 31 columns representing days. There are no performance issues at all if you do it right. There is no lazy loading, though - all columns are displayed at once. How long is your timeline that you consider lazy loading? I would recommend something like "Next month"/"Previous month" approach rather than loading on scroll.

Comment: the timeline doesn't have a precise limit but we are talking about years...lazy load is mandatory

Comment: Are you talking a century or something :)? In either case, you can easily use lazy loading with my proposed solution. Lazy loading has nothing to do with the widget that displays data.

Comment: I know lazy load is something in provider but since provider works by range and range for data grid is by rows doesn't fit. I'm trying to implement a custom widget but as you can read in my edit i'm no successful in creating scrollbars

Comment: You don't have to use the provider for lazy loading, just the same approach. Or you can override it to use columns instead of rows.

Comment: Can you provide an example? as far as i know the event related to the range change works only by rows